# Android - Change Notification Icon

Tags: android

I would like to know if its possible to have an different Notificationbar Icon than the Launcher or Application Icon. I would like to display an other icon for my push notifications. Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For API < 11, the `Notification` constructor allowed an [icon to be specified](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#Notification%28int,%20java.lang.CharSequence,%20long%29). For API > 10, the `setSmallIcon` and `setLargeIcon` methods for [Notifcation.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html) allow much the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Notification n  = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
                    .setContentText("Subject")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Call", pIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "More", pIntent)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "And more", pIntent).build();


    NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, n);
```

in above code `setSmallIcon` and `setSmallIcon` are for change the notification icon