# Changing the notification icon

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-notifications

I would like to set another default icon for my notification. I use the notification service of [parse.com](http://www.parse.com) and would like to change the icon in the notification bar.

Is that possible without changing the title and the text with `Notification.Builder`?

Comment: Are you meaning you are using the [Push Notifications of Parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#push) or what? Please edit your question and be way more specific.

Comment: yes and I would like to use an other icon for my notifications, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Post your source code on how you create your notification.

But in general, to change the notification icon, you just call the method setSmallIcon or setLargeIcon. Here's an example:

```
 Notification notif = new Notification.Builder()
     .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .build();
```

In your case, just supply a different icon drawable to the setSmallIcon method.

Comment: user1253575, you already asked this in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379518/android-change-notification-icon) and got an answer there which included that info. If that was still unclear to you, then ask there.

Answer (score 1):

In android lower than ICS

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logo, "", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.largeIcon = your bitmap
notification.icon = your drawable
```

Comment: I dont know why but this isn't working. Is there something you have to set up first? Any Permissions ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D Hmm, I think it did work after calling an other constructor of the Notification class (Can't remember though, it has been more than a year since I posted this question). However, the answer azgolfer posted is actually better (and is now - through the support lib - available for lower Android versions ). I reaccepted the question. Thanks for pointing that out! :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement a custom receiver for the Parse Push Notifications as [described in Parse's documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#push-receiving).

By doing this, Parse is not automatically generating a User Notification in Android and you can then do this yourself with `Notification.Builder` in newer Android version and `Notification()` in older Android version as described in the other answers and there provide your custom icon.