# How to customize push notification icon?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am using ParsePush to send notifications to my Android users. I want to customize the notification icon that appears in the action bar.

Currently the app launcher icon is being displayed. But I want to change that and use a different icon for notifications.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Change Notification Icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379518/android-change-notification-icon)

Comment: NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
    context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.applogo)

Comment: I asked about changing icon with ParsePush @Shane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved using overloaded function

```
setDefaultPushCallback(Context context, Class<? extends Activity> cls, int icon)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( context).setSmallIcon(@android:drawable/btn_star)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
            .setContentText(notificationMessage)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE)
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setStyle(bigStyle);

    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationmanager.notify(nofy_id, builder.build());
```